# Column cannot return the measure values - DAX divide function and filters

Tags: function, dax, measure

I would love to do some slicer filtering (icon based) - which I already did and it works for me well when I have the values in columns. I have the issue when I wanted to use measures instead of columns.

I am not allowed to connect measures in data model with table "Icons YTD", therefore I decided to create column (column could be connected in data model with my icon table). I tried everything but the results are every time wrong.

Picture available here:

[image: 1]

**Measure works:**

```
Actual/Planned Hours [%] - MEASURE = DIVIDE([YTD Actual Hours],[YTD Planned Hours])
```

**Column doesn't works: (shows everywhere 0)** even the same calculation is used

```
Actual/Planned Hours [%] - COLUMN = DIVIDE([YTD Actual Hours],[YTD Planned Hours])
```

or I tried

```
Actual/Planned Hours [%] - COLUMN = Hours[Actual/Planned Hours [%] - MEASURE]
```

and I tried lot of more, but nothing helped me.

**Calculated and used measures for calculations above:**

```
YTD Actual Hours = CALCULATE(SUM(Hours[Actual Hours]), Months[YTD Months]=true,ALLEXCEPT(Hours, Hours[ID], Hours[P],Hours[D], Hours[Actual Hours]))

YTD Planned Hours = CALCULATE(SUM(Hours[Planned Hours]), Months[YTD Months]=true,ALLEXCEPT(Hours, Hours[ID], Hours[P],Hours[D], Hours[Planned Hours]))
```

Do you have any idea how to create it?
Thank you a lot!

Comment: What error It produces as you write your DAX Code  in the column ?

Comment: [YTD Actual Hours] is a column name in your table ? OR It is a measure you created beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with icons and everything to do with the fact that you cannot filter by measures without jumping through some hoops. Here is a [very good video](https://youtu.be/miiGlDWeamM) on filtering with measures.